Test whether a string is in a list
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{currfile}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \IfStringInList {mmmm}
  { \clist_if_in:nnTF {#2} {#1} {#3} {#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

Name of the pupil: \currfilebase\\

\IfStringInList{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{On the list}{Not on the list}\\

\IfStringInList{Paul}{\input{D:/folder1/folder2/Testliste.tex}}{On the list}{Not on the list}\\

\IfStringInList{\currfilebase}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{On the list}{Not on the list}\\

\end{document}

I want to add some code to a given document. For these purposes I adopted some code from @@cgnieder Package to test whether a string is in a list (all credits to @cgnieder) and tried some modifications: The above code is saved under the name "Paul.tex". The above code works very nice giving me the right answer (i.e. Paul is "On the list") but when I try to import the names from an external file "Testliste.tex" (which is just the comma separated name list "George,John,Paul,Ringo") via the \input command (see third "sentence") I get the wrong answer that "Paul" is "Not on the list". Furthermore the \currfilebase command in the forth "sentence" is also ignored although it works in the first row. How can I fix these errors? Any help is greatly appreciated!

You'll probably need to have the second arg expanded. Try putting \ExpArgs{ne}  before the relevant ones (untested, not at pc)

My suggestion is to use a * variant that expects a file name.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.list}
George,John,Paul,Ringo
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \IfStringInList {smmmm}
 {% #1 = optional *; in this case #3 has to be a file name
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% we want a file
    % load it
    \file_get:nnN {#3} {} \l__mario_inlist_file_tl
    % normalize into a clist
    \clist_set:NV \l__mario_inlist_file_clist \l__mario_inlist_file_tl
    \clist_if_in:NnTF \l__mario_inlist_file_clist {#2} {#4} {#5}
   }
   {% explicit list
    \clist_if_in:nnTF {#3} {#2} {#4} {#5}
   }
 }
\tl_new:N \l__mario_inlist_file_tl
\clist_new:N \l__mario_inlist_file_clist
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IfStringInList{Paul}{George,John,Paul,Ringo}{On the list}{Not on the list}

\IfStringInList*{Paul}{\jobname.list}{On the list}{Not on the list}

\end{document}

You get “On the list” in both cases.

A very big thank you! That did the trick!

Here is small addendum to your answer: I extended the name list in the second row to 12 names:  \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.list}
George,John,Paul,Ringo,Olaf,Petra,Nicole,Frank,Peter,Damian,Egon,Olga
\end{filecontents*}. Regarding the last two code lines after compilation I get the right answer of who is in the list as long as I don´t choose the 9th name (Peter) and above since then I get the wrong answer from the code line \IfStringInList*{Damian}{\jobname.list}{On the list}{Not on the list} "Not on the list" although e.g Damian is defintely on the list. How can I fix this? Thx

@mario1000 I used filecontents* just in order to make the example self-contained. You probably aren't recreating the file, because by default filecontents* will not overwrite an existing file. If I recreate the file with the twelve names in it, I have no problem with any of the names.

My mistake, sorry! You are right now everything works very well. Thanks again for your help!

May I asked a final question to your solution: A colleague if mine is interested in your solution as well but he came to the idea that instead using "\IfStringInList*{Paul}" in the last row of your code he suggested something like "\IfStringInList*{\currfilebase}" or "\IfStringInList*{\jobname}" in order to get a more general solution if the name on the jobname.list and thus of the file name itself changes drastically.  Can this be done with your code? Thanks a lot for your help!

@mario1000 Sorry, but I don't understand. In the example, \jobname.list is used in place of any file name. If the file containing the names to be checked is called listofnames.foo, then you use \IfStringInList*{listofnames.foo}{Paul}
